# How to display button only for newly added value using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hi can any one please help me with this.

When click on add button a new field will be generated. Except that new empty field all other field should be disabled and Save button should be displayed for newly added empty field.

I have create a sample fiddle. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/30079/)

```
 <tr ng-show="!isCollapsed[$index]" ng-repeat="item in adddivsubdivValues">
        <td></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="div" class="form-control4" autocomplete="off" id="div_{{$index}}" value={{item.div}}>
        <td>
    <input type="text" name="div" class="form-control4" autocomplete="off" id="subdiv_{{$index}}" value={{item.subdiv}}>
    </td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;" ng-click="saveDivSubDiv($index)" ng-if="displaysavebutton">Save</button></td>
        <td><a href ng-click="removeDivSubDiv($index)">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display save button when newly added input button is empty.

```
$scope.addDivSubDiv = function() {
    var index = $scope.adddivsubdivValues.length;
    console.log(index);
    $scope.initialarraysize = index;

    /* Remaining code */
};

<tr ng-show="!isCollapsed[$index]" ng-repeat="item in adddivsubdivValues">
        <td></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="div" class="form-control4" autocomplete="off" id="div_{{$index}}" value={{item.div}} ng-disabled="$index != initialarraysize">
        <td>
    <input type="text" name="div" class="form-control4" autocomplete="off" id="subdiv_{{$index}}" value={{item.subdiv}} ng-disabled="$index != initialarraysize">
    </td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;" ng-click="saveDivSubDiv($index)" ng-show="$index == initialarraysize">Save</button></td>
        <td><a href ng-click="removeDivSubDiv($index)">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
```